# How to send data and a Image using HttpClient w.post?

Tags: c#, php, laravel, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I need to perform a post method using `HttpClient` and capture it in my PHP web service.

At the first time, I was starting using a FormUrlEncodedContent and that's okay, my web service received these data. But now I need that the user capture an image and get it in a byte array.

For this, I guess MultipartFormDataContent is the heroe here. This is what I have

```
        Dictionary<string, string> @params = new Diction ...
        byte[] imageData = ...

        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        requestContent.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(@params));
        requestContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageData));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(request, requestContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But when I receive the response, I get the following:

> responseBody  "
> \n**Warning**:  File Upload Mime headers
>   garbled in **Unknown** on line **0**
> \n{\"…"   string

I don't know if there's a problem in the php code or in my c# code.

Answer (score 0):

we had similar problem - and we had to get rid of HttpClient as it's not very flexible. In our case, we had to upload multiple files to the server. We ended up using WebRequest. Working code is below. Look at **PostMultipart** function - everything else are helpers.

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public UploadFile(Stream data, string fieldName, string fileName, string contentType)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.FieldName = fieldName;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.ContentType = contentType;
    }

    public UploadFile(string fileAbsPath, string fieldName, string fileName, string contentType)
        : this(File.OpenRead(fileAbsPath), fieldName, fileName, contentType)
    {
    }

    public UploadFile(string fileAbsPath, string fieldName, string contentType)
        : this(fileAbsPath, fieldName, Path.GetFileName(fileAbsPath), contentType)
    {
    }


    public UploadFile(string fileAbsPath)
        : this(fileAbsPath, null, Path.GetFileName(fileAbsPath), "application/octet-stream")
    {
    }

    public Stream Data { get; set; }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? ModificationDate { get; set; }
}

class MimePart
{
    private readonly NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
    private byte[] header;

    private Stream data;

    public override Stream Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data;
        }
    }

    public void SetStream(Stream stream)
    {
        this.data = stream;
    }

    public NameValueCollection Headers
    {
        get { return this.headers; }
    }

    public byte[] Header
    {
        get { return this.header; }
    }

    public long GenerateHeaderFooterData(string boundary)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--");
        sb.Append(boundary);
        sb.AppendLine();

        foreach (string key in this.headers.AllKeys)
        {
            sb.Append(key);
            sb.Append(": ");
            sb.AppendLine(this.headers[key]);
        }

        sb.AppendLine();

        this.header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        return this.header.Length + this.Data.Length + 2;
    }
}

private IList<MimePart> GenerateMimePartsList(IEnumerable<UploadFile> files)
{
    var mimeParts = new List<MimePart>();

    int nameIndex = 0;

    // Files data
    foreach (UploadFile file in files)
    {
        var streamMimePart = new StreamMimePart();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FieldName))
        {
            file.FieldName = "file" + nameIndex++;
        }

        var contentDispositionValues = new List<string>();
        contentDispositionValues.Add("form-data");
        contentDispositionValues.Add(string.Format("name=\"{0}\"", file.FieldName));
        contentDispositionValues.Add(string.Format("filename=\"{0}\"", file.FileName));

        if (file.CreationDate.HasValue)
        {
            contentDispositionValues.Add(string.Format("creation-date=\"{0}\"", file.CreationDate.Value.ToString("R")));
        }

        if (file.ModificationDate.HasValue)
        {
            contentDispositionValues.Add(string.Format("modification-date=\"{0}\"", file.ModificationDate.Value.ToString("R")));
        }

        // "form-data; name=\"" + file.FieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + file.FileName + "\"";
        streamMimePart.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Join("; ", contentDispositionValues);
        streamMimePart.Headers["Content-Type"] = file.ContentType;
        streamMimePart.SetStream(file.Data);

        mimeParts.Add(streamMimePart);
    }

    return mimeParts;
}

public void PostMultipart(Uri uri, IEnumerable<UploadFile> files)
{
    var mimeParts = this.GenerateMimePartsList(files);

    var boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    request.ContentLength = mimeParts.Sum(part => part.GenerateHeaderFooterData(boundary)) + footer.Length;
    try
    {
        // Write data
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        byte[] afterFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            foreach (MimePart mimePart in mimeParts)
            {
                requestStream.Write(mimePart.Header, 0, mimePart.Header.Length);

                int read;
                while ((read = mimePart.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                mimePart.Data.Dispose();

                requestStream.Write(afterFile, 0, afterFile.Length);
            }

            requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
        }

        // Get response 
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseText = response.ReadAsString();


            return;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        this.HandleErrorResponse(webException);
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var mimePart in mimeParts)
        {
            if (mimePart.Data != null)
            {
                mimePart.Data.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```